# The best way passing value from jQuery to PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I wonder how I can pass value from Jquery to PHP. I found similar codes but not even one of them work.
Everytime  alert shows value of variable but when I open site there is not any. Var_dump shows that $_POST is null. I am ran out of ideas do you have any?

jQuery code:

```
$("#password-button").click(function(){
 var password="";
 var numbers =[0,0,0,0,0,0];
 for(var i=0;i<=5;i++){
    numbers[i] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + 65);
    password += String.fromCharCode(numbers[i]);
 }
   $(".LoginError").text("Nowe haslo: " + password);

  $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'dzialaj.php',
                    data: {'password': password},
                    cache:false,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        alert(data);
                         console.log(result)
        console.log(result.status);
                    }
                });

});
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['password'])){
$temp = $_POST['password'];
echo $temp;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here so it is preserved for future SO visitors.

Comment: Use AJAX to pass data from Javascript to PHP. It's hard to be of any more help with such a vague question.

Comment: AJAX is how you pass values from jQuery to PHP.

Comment: AJAX is the solution

Comment: I know that Ajax is the solution. When I check data parameter has value inside but in php the value is gone, it is null. I do not know why.

Comment: post your HTML form that goes with this. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and check your console.

Comment: where are you setting `result`? suggest using `POST` for your `type` also. And as @Fred-ii- says, use the console

Comment: I have a 5 minute span of attention. I am out of this question. @ me if you want and when you posted your HTML form that should have been posted in the first place. Good luck, I am moving on... *ciao!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Which form? I do not have any. This is just function, create some random string after user clicked button.
jQuery code works fine i think cause I can generate random string and alert shows this value. Problem is with PHP code. var_dump($_POST['password'] always shows null. $_POST['password'] is never set I guess but I can not figure out why

Comment: what does `var_dump($_REQUEST)` show? Use firefox/chrome & inspect the network traffic to see what HTTP request headers are being sent to your script. If the headers are being sent but PHP can't see them, there must be something odd with your PHP installation

Answer (score 6):

Since it looks like you are new on ajax, let's try something more simple ok? Check this `js`:

```
<script>
var string = "my string"; // What i want to pass to php

 $.ajax({
    type: 'post', // the method (could be GET btw)
    url: 'output.php', // The file where my php code is
    data: {
        'test': string // all variables i want to pass. In this case, only one.
    },
    success: function(data) { // in case of success get the output, i named data
        alert(data); // do something with the output, like an alert
    }
});
</script>
```

Now my **output.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['test'])) { //if i have this post
    echo $_POST['test']; // print it
}
```

So basically i have a `js` variable and used in my `php` code. If i need a response i could get it from `php` and return it to `js` like the variable `data` does.

Everything working so far? Great. Now replace the `js` mentioned above with your current code. Before run the `ajax` just do an `console.log` or `alert` to check if you variable `password` is what you expect. If it's not, you need to check what's wrong with your `js` or `html` code.

Here is a example what i think you are trying to achieve (not sure if i understand correctly)

**EDIT**

```
<script>
var hash = "my hash";

 $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'output.php',
    data: {
        'hash': hash        },
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == 'ok') {
            alert('All good. Everything saved!');
        } else {
            alert('something went wrong...');
        } 
    }
});
</script>
```

Now my **output.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['hash'])) {
    //run sql query saving what you need in your db and check if the insert/update was successful;
    // im naming my verification $result (a boolean)
    if ($result) echo 'ok';
    else echo 'error';
}
```

Since the page won't redirect to the php, you need a response in you ajax to know what was the result of you php code (if was successful or not).

Here is the others answers i mentioned in the coments:

[How to redirect through 'POST' method using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064352/how-to-redirect-through-post-method-using-javascript)

[Send POST data on redirect with Javascript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389646/send-post-data-on-redirect-with-javascript-jquery)

[jQuery - Redirect with post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036684/jquery-redirect-with-post-data)

[Javascript - redirect to a page with POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774533/javascript-redirect-to-a-page-with-post-data)

Comment: all clear thanks. This is the same way how my jQuery code works.
When you open in browser output.php do you see value "my string"?
The problem is that I can not, even using your code

Comment: Sure you can't. If you open the php file directly there won't be the post you set in your js. Same thing if you use GET parameters instead. The purpose of this ajax is with your js script, you run you php code as well. If you are going to access the php directly you probably don't need the js part.

Comment: As you can see the php file only works if someone open the file with the post parameter expected. Just like the js does.

Comment: "If you open the php file directly there won't be the post you set in your js".Even if I open window with javascript first? What I think it  works:
User open site, click button, some random string generate, send to php, user open new window(with this php  code this time)  and see this generated string. Am I right?

Comment: It does'nt works that way. Is more like: User open an site > User fills a form and click the submit > js is triggered and get the inputs > js call the ajax to a php code > php code do what it needs to do with the information given and can output a response to js > js gets the response and show to the user (if that is the case) > User didn't had to leave the page to get the response of the form.

Comment: The real point of this is the user don't need to go to the other page. If the user have to do... would not be better just make a form and submit to that page?

Comment: "would not be better just make a form and submit to that page?". I have only one value. Maybe I should tell what I want achive. This function in jQuery generate random string. I want save to database this value. This value does not need to be send back to site because php code will send this to database. I know that the idea of Ajax is not to re-load page. "... and see this generated string." I meant that was control point for me to check if everything is ok but I noticed that is not because echo does not display values which I generate

Comment: Maybe I was wrong. I wanted to echo value from jQuery but maybe it does not work that way. Should I make header to output.php from site where I generate string? and the second header should be from output.php to site where I generate string?(Just like logout from session() ) ? but instead of unset variables and destroy session send value to database. Am I right these time?

Comment: I updated the answer, not sure i understand 100% though. If you really need to go to the php page (as you asked before). You could see this answers for "how to redirect to a page sending POST" . Spoiler: most of than says to you make a hidden form and submit it. :)

Comment: I do not need to go to the php page. I just want jQuery value send to database. I thought that I could pass value to php and later connect to database but in the middle of work I noticed that $_POST in php file gives me only null not value from jQuery function and here I am few hours and 2 pages of Google search later

Comment: I vote for this answer because it has a very detailed description (comments) and helped me understand how to make a simple ajax call. Thank you